# The repository [name] has been retired and cannot be reused

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository

Recently I've renamed my Github.com account, then I return to the old name after that one of my old repositories retired without any reason + now I can't create a new repository with the same name!

The error message:

```
The repository [name] has been retired and cannot be reused
```

[image]

Is there any solution, or should I contact Github.com support team?

Comment: You already have a repo with that name that has been archived... If you can't find or delete it, contact Github support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a same issue.
I contected Github Support. And I got an answer.

> Steve Graff (GitHub Support)
> Sep 22, 2020, 2:53 PM UTC
> Hi Im, Thanks for reaching out to GitHub Support.
> I have unretired that repository name for you.
> Here is the reason it was retired, by the way:
> https://github.blog/2018-04-18-new-tools-for-open-source-maintainers/#popular-repository-namespace-retirement If there's anything else I can do, give me a shout!
> Thanks,
> Steve G.
> GitHub Support

Now, It is working well :D

Comment: Is there a lifetime to this retirement period or is it permanent?

Comment: [this](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-your-personal-account/deleting-your-personal-account) says it is permanent

Answer (score 0):

First change your username to another name, then set the repository name you want, and finally change the username back, and you're done.

Comment: fwiw this did not work for me

Comment: Have you solved it？

Comment: I ended up contacting support and they did their magic 

Comment: That's great, I'm glad your issue was resolved.